# How to create row labels for a PivotTable?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have:

```
name     state  office  income   
Steeve   IL     1         1000
Steeve   IL     9         2000
Mary     CA     2         2000
Mary     CA     3         5000
Mary     CA     33        3000
Alex     DC     13       11000
Michael  Al     22        2000
  .............
```

I need to create a PivotTable such that in the `Row labels` are `name` and `state`, to look like this:

```
    name     state      income   
    Steeve   IL           3000
    Mary     CA          10000
    Alex     DC          11000
    Michael  Al           2000
      .............
```

As I tried to include `name` and `state` in the `Row labels` box, the result was not they way I expected. There was one column of `name` and `state` combined.

How can I create such a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the PT and you should see a Design tab (in the Ribbon). Click on that and in Layout, Report Layout choose Show in Tabular Form.